Webpage Background Color Change Resulting in Divided Page with 'grammarly-desktop-integration' Element: How to Fix?
I was trying to change the entire bg-color for my webpage and the page gets divided into two parts and the second part shows this:
<grammarly-desktop-integration data-grammarly-shadow-root="true"></grammarly-desktop-integration>

How do I reslove this?
I tried applying new div tag for overall page and i tried it in different browsers and it didn't work.
